# C++ array calculator

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, output

for my assignment i have to create a array calculator but my teacher asked me to display it/ output it as Answer: 2 + 1 + 3 = 6 (random numbers as example) I was wondering what variable do i need to put in place of the "2" "1" and "3" spot? in order for it to display like the example. Maybe I need to create a variable for each one? if so pls show me an example. I shall copy and paste what i have so far, i'm using visiual studios by the way.

```
// Preprocessor Directives
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

/*
 * Name:            main()
 * Parameters:      None.
 * Processes:       Replace this text; see the instructions in the Template.
 * Return Value:    An integer representing an error code; if the program ends without error, zero 
 *                  will be returned to the calling program or operating system.
 */
int main()
{
    // Constants and Variables
    const int SIZE = 3;
    double number[SIZE] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, sum = 0.0, difference = 0.0, product = 0.0, quotient = 0.0,
        average = 0.0, largest = 0.0, num = 0.0;
    int i;
    bool numsGotten = false;
    char choice = '\0';

    // Output - Format
    cout << setprecision(3) << fixed;
    
    // Process - Calculator Menu  

    do
    {
        cout << "\nCalculator Menu\n\n"
            << "(G)et three numbers.\n"
            << "(A)dd.\n"
            << "(S)ubtract.\n"
            << "(M)ultiply.\n"
            << "(D)ivide.\n"
            << "a(V)erage.\n"
            << "(L)argest.\n"
            << "(P)ositive, negative, or zero.\n"
            << "e(X)it.\n\n"
            << "Choice: ";  
    
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        // New Numbers
            case 'G':
            case 'g':   
        // Input - Numbers 
        cout << "\nEnter numbers: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            cin >> number[i];
            //Validation
            numsGotten = true;
        }
        break;
        // Addition
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                // Validation
                if (numsGotten)
                {

                    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                    {
                        sum += number[i];
                    }
                        
                    // Output - Answer
                    cout << "\nAnswer: " <<  << " + " << i++ << " + " << i++ << " = " << sum << ".\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Output - Error
                    cout << "\n\tError: Please select option G from the menu first!\n";
                }
                break;

            // Exit
            case 'X':
            case 'x':
                // Output - Thank You Message
                cout << "\nThank you for using Brianna's calculator! Good-bye!\n";
                break;

            // Invalid Choice
            default:
                // Output - Error
                cout << "\n\tError: Invalid choice!\n";
        }
    }
    while (choice != 'x' && choice != 'X');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The numbers are in the array you read in.  That's what you output.  There is no need to create variables, since the array is the "variable" that holds the information you inputted.

Answer (score 0):

For this question, I have written a small sample to make it easier for you to understand. In this sample I create an array with 3 numbers, where the value of a[0] is 1, the value of a[1] is 2 and the value of a[2] is 3. You could use this method to call the numbers in the array.

```
int main()
{
    int a[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]